# cash box status in browsers (jquery)

Tags: jquery, caching

I have a question about the use of cash in jquery:

A simple code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.close_i').click(function(){
$('.adsbox').hide();
$('.open_i').show();
});

$('.open_i').click(function(){
$('.adsbox').show();
$('.open_i').hide();
});

});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="adsbox">
<img src="as1.jpg">
<img src="as2.jpg">
<img src="as3.jpg">
<img src="as4.jpg">
<img src="as5.jpg">
<img src="as6.jpg">
<a class="close_i">Close ADS</a>
</div>
<a class="open_i" style="display:none;">Open ADS</a>
</body>
```

As you can see, this is a simple code to hide or show a ads box.

I want to cache and saved the box status in the user's browser to for 3 days.

Please guide me. Thankful

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery Cookie [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

Set cookie value:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 3 }); //Expires in 3 days
```

Read cookie value:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the HTML5 [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

There are 2 objects you can use:

- window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
- code.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed)

If you want the keep the status in cache for 3 day, you'll have to use the window.localStorage. Since you cannot specify an expiration date, you'll have to provide a timestamp and validate the expiration on your own.